# Setting domain hint in the new Microsoft Graph Tool Kit

Tags: reactjs, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I'm updating some we apps to use the Graph Tool Kit (React). I’m using this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/get-started/use-toolkit-with-react - I can't find documentation on where/how to plug-in the domainHint property (as we typically can with MSAL). Any chance someone already used it and can point me to it?

Comment: Please search for `domainHint` in github or open issue in their github repositories. Generally it would be nice if you post code

Comment: I assume you want to use `domainHint` while signing in with the `MsalProvider`? If so, we don't support that right now, but happy to add it to the provider as part of the config object. Do you mind opening an issue here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/issues

Comment: That's correct, I'm using MsalProvier. It doesn't seem to have the extraQueryParameters property used to set the domain hint in MSAL. It has an "options" property to set other stuff like cache but that on is not accepting extraQueryParameters.

Comment: + opening issue in GitHub. Thanks Nikola.